# ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG slow broadcast response

Tags: android

I want my music player to pause music when the  ear-phones are disconnected, and to resume music when the ear phones are re-connected. I got this set up to work with a broad cast receiver, but the problem is I can hear music playing from the speakers a split second after I disconnect the ear phones. It's like my receiver is not receiving the broad cast quickly enough? What's going on?

Here I register my receiver in my `onCreate` method in my main activity class

```
MusicIntentReceiver receiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

Here is my intent receiver class

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {

            if(intent.getIntExtra("state",0)==0){ // 0 for unplugged (if it becomes unplugged)

                //Pause music
            }

            if(intent.getIntExtra("state",0)==1){ // 1 for plugged (if it becomes plugged)

                //Resume music
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to Pause music on `AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` - it it comes before `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` (approx. about 1 sec). Something like:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
filter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
registerReceiver(receiverHeadset, filter);
```

...

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
            // Pause music
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {

            if(intent.getIntExtra("state",0)==1){ // 1 for plugged (if it becomes plugged)

                //Resume music
            }
        }
    }
}
```